# Late Bind on msoFileDialogFilePicker

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am self taught in VBA, which is probably the worst kind, and I still consider myself a novice. There are some things I just can't understand and this site has been a godsend. This code is not my own, so I barely understand what it is doing, which makes it difficult to alter. It's been working for the past two years. The company is now slowly upgrading computers and we now have some running Office 2010 and some running 2013. That means I can no longer use Office Tool references in my code, because it breaks between systems. So long story short, I need to do a late binding on this bit of code and I have no idea how.
I get an error on msoFileDialogFilePicker and msoFileDialogViewList
Please Overflow community, HELP!

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False 'Select only one file
    .Title = "Locate file" 'Set dialog title
    .ButtonName = "Choose" 'Set the button caption
    .Filters.Clear 'Make sure the filter list is clear
    .InitialFileName = "\\PUSNBF02\common\Admin\New EA's\" 'Initial file search location
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList 'View as list
    'Show the dialog and test the return
    If .Show = 0 Then 'didn't pick a file - exit sub
        Exit Function
    Else
       'Should be only one file name - grab it
        SourceFile = Trim(.SelectedItems(1))  'Full path of file
        strSource = SourceFile
        strSourcePath = Left(strSource, InStrRev(strSource, "\"))
        strSourceFileName = Mid(strSource, InStrRev(strSource, "\") + 1)
        strSourceExtension = Right(strSource, Len(strSource) - InStrRev(strSource, "."))
        'Debug.Print strSourceExtension
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace them with the appropriate numbers.

You can look up these numbers either by typing `?msoFileDialogFilePicker` in the immediate window if you have it early-bound, by looking them up in the object browser, or, plain Google.

The corresponding number for `msoFileDialogFilePicker` is 3, so you can replace it with that:

```
With Application.FileDialog(3)
    '...
    .InitialView = 1 'View as list
    '...
```

Comment: It is better (i.e. more readable) to declare a global constant such as `Global Const MSO_FILE_DIALOG_FILE_PICKER = 3` at the top of a code module, and then use `With Application.FileDialog(MSO_FILE_DIALOG_FILE_PICKER)`.

Comment: When I add in the global variable I still error on msoFileDialogViewList
How can I fix that one?

Comment: I don't follow you Erik, I'm sorry.

Comment: I figured it out Erik! I had to add the reference tools back in to get the number. Thank you!

Comment: @Applecore Valid, I usually just do `With Application.FileDialog(3) 'msoFileDialogFilePicker` to not have constants all over the place, but avoided that in this answer to not insinuate that it's needed.

Comment: @ErikA That's a good idea. I think I'll add that in, so when I'm looking at this code in confusion later on I have an idea what it means.